Custom rsyslog Rule Not Logging to Specific File in Yocto Project on Ubuntu
I am working on a Yocto Project running on Ubuntu and have configured rsyslog to route log messages from a specific program to a custom log file. However, the messages don't seem to be logged as per my rule. I have a rule in a separate configuration file in /etc/rsyslog.d/ that matches the program name "diagnostic" and should log these messages to /var/log/myApp-diagnostics.log. Despite placing the rule in a file that should load early, messages are still ending up in default logs like user.log.
I have so far:

Created a file in /etc/rsyslog.d/ named 00-myApp-rsyslog.conf to ensure it loads first.
The rule is set to match the program name and stop further processing:

if $programname == 'diagnostic' then /var/log/myApp-diagnostics.log
& stop


The file has permissions for rsyslog to write to them.

Testing - Using the logger command with -p local0.info -t diagnostic "Test message for diagnostics log" works as expected, and the message is logged correctly to /var/log/myApp-diagnostics.log.


Observed Log Output:
With "diagnostic":
2024-10-03T15:40:12.400343+00:00 qemux86-64 Test message: Diagnostic from some_function

With "iagnostic" (When the program name is incorrect):
 <12>1 2024-10-03T15:40:21.090797+00:00 hostname myApp 111 iagnostic - filename.py:56 INFO: Test message: Diagnostic from some_function

